# Facebook Integration Post From Phone Gallery

Tags: android, facebook, post, gallery, photo

This may be a question that has already been asked, so please forgive me if that is the case,I have just had a hard time locating a concrete answer.  In my app,I would like to be able to post images from a users phone gallery to the wall.  I know how to already share to the wall using a basic Intent, but I am using Facebook API Integration for this, so that I can post from the app and let people know that I am posting from the app (I have already done the needed steps on Facebook for integration and am already logging in using Facebook).

In my searching of the Facebook Documentation for Android, I have only been able to find information on posting with an image URL, which is NOT what I would like to do.  Is there any sort of documentation out there that would help me understand how to share not with an image URL, but the URI?  Is this even possible, or am I just chasing something that doesn't exist?  Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> so that I can post from the app and let people know that I am posting from the app.

For this you have to create a Facebook application from the Facebook developer site. Read this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/link-to-your-native-app/

> Is there any sort of documentation out there that would help me understand how to share not with an image URL, but the URI? Is this even possible, or am I just chasing something that doesn't exist?

Yes, you can post images directly from the phone.Refer this link:

[Facebook Image upload](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Request#newUploadPhotoRequest%28Session,%20File,%20Callback%29)

Hope This helps